# Could not find Biometric system that could send data directly to web server

Tags: biometrics

I need a biometric (RFID or FINGER PRINT or face recognition) system which could consume web api directly - being independent of third party. I got some CAMS biometric unit and ZKTECO K20 pro model these could send data to server but we must go through their data server and need to expose the API. I want biometric system that could send activity data to my server.

This is required to develop a system to control attendance of branches from cooperate office. Here I need some suggestion of biometric system. I got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a biometric device with its default software on your computer. The software stores the attendance data in your local database. You can develop a software to read the data from the local database and update your server on a schedule.

Online SDK is restricted from the manufacturers as it may lead to the security issues. As it is online based, anyone can access the anyone's biometric device if the online SDK has been exposed. So it is kept as confidential by the manufacturers CAMS and ZKTeco.

You can make your CAMS devices to communicate with your server directly, Below is the text snippet taken from their API documentation link: http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html

> Want to receive data without coming through CAMS Dataserver?
>
> Yes. We provide the windows lite version protocol engine which should be
>   installed at your windows server. Once its installed, You web api
>   endpoints will start getting triggered whenever attendance is
>   registered at the device