# Can you send log data from a biometric device to a web server?

Tags: php, api, websocket, webserver, biometrics

We have this Realand Fingerprint Recognition device here in our office and I have to connect it to a web based PHP attendance management system. But I don't have any idea if i can directly connect it. I'm currently looking for its documentation but it doesn't seems to have a PHP related guide on how can I get data from this biometrics device. There are some SDK here which are using demo websocket but it can't detect the device. Also, I'm not familiar with VB or C#. Any possible way that is flexible on most of biometric device that you can suggest? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the Web API supported biometric attendance devices. Realand doest support the communication you are looking for. Please check the following answer which would address your question: [Could not find Biometric system that could send data directly to web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277828/could-not-find-biometric-system-that-could-send-data-directly-to-web-server/52417186#52417186)

Comment: Thanks Ramshri. Do you have any idea if are there any biometric brands that supports Web API aside from CAMS and ZKTeco?

Comment: @JLacandola, At present, only CAMS provides the API even for ZkTeco devices. The API document is available at camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html. It is a chargeable API. No free API is available in the market for now.